# laravel checking user enbaled always true for positive integer

Tags: laravel

Returning always true in laravel user model for positive integer

```
class User extends .....
{
protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    'enabled' => 'boolean',
    ];



public function isEnabled(): bool
    {
        return $this->enabled == 1 ? true : false;
    }

}
```

in MySQL Table

enabled       is     tinyint unsigned

in controller

```
$user->isEnabled() //Returning always true in laravel user model for positive integer
```

Comment: If you cast `enabled` as `boolean` you don't need to check is it `== 1` or not, because value is already true or false. Just do this `return $this->enabled;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `enabled`  feld  as tinyint and you have said true for all positve integer ; so rewrite as below

```
protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    'enabled' => 'boolean', // remove this line  as you casting enabled as boolen which returns true on positive integer
    ];
```